# IsAuthenticated is always false in Custom Authorization Attribute (.NET Core 2.2 and JSON Web Token)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I'm trying to build my own custom authorization attribute using JSON Web Token `JWT` in .net core 2.2.

I'm calling the Authorized API using **Postman** and I'm facing two problems here:

1. The Claims in the `JWT` sent are not being received
2. `IsAuthenticated` property is always false in `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.

Please note that the part of `JWT` is working totally fine, a `JWT` is being created as I want with the correct `Claims` and I've checked it on https://jwt.io.

As for my `Startup.cs` I'm using `app.UseAuthentication()`

Here's how I'm adding the `JWTAuthentication` to `services`:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x=>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And here's a snippet of `MyCustomAuthorizationAttribute.cs`

```
    public string Permissions { get; set; } //Permission string to get from controller

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        //Validate if any permissions are passed when using attribute at controller or action level
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Permissions))
        {
            //Validation cannot take place without any permissions so returning unauthorized
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }


        //The below line can be used if you are reading permissions from token
        var permissionsFromToken = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "Permissions").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

        var requiredPermissions = Permissions.Split(','); //Multiple permissiosn can be received from controller, delimiter "," is used to get individual values
        foreach (var x in requiredPermissions)
        {
            if (permissionsFromToken.Contains(x))
                return; //User Authorized. Wihtout setting any result value and just returning is sufficent for authorizing user
        }

        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        return;
    }
```

**Note:** I know that this question is asked a lot before, but I tried most of them and nothing worked for me.

Comment: How did you get the `Permissions` in your `MyCustomAuthorizationAttribute`?Please note that you need to set `ValidateIssuer` and `ValidateAudience`.And be sure you have add the claim with type named `Permissions`.Refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/58163087/11398810

Comment: Yes everything you've mentioned was already there, but surprisingly the issue was only about ordering middlewares in `Startup.cs`  And permissions was being fetched from database based on the user logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the order of putting the middleware services in `Startup.cs` matters. As we can see in the code snippet above. I'm using `AddIdentity()` middleware after using `AddAuthentication()` and `AddJwtBearer()` which was somehow removing the JWT authentication provider.

The solution was simply to put `AddIdentity()` middleware with all of its sub-methods before `AddAuthentication()` and `AddJWTBearer()` middlware.