# I m using AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi .net core 6 with MSAL. can I create my custom middleware?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication, azure-identity

I m using AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi .net core 6 . Can I create my custom middleware ?

below is my code.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

can we add custom middleware for Microsoft identity ?

Comment: Please check if you can do [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154183/custom-middleware-with-jwt-authorization-isauthenticated-false) by using azuread . see [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score -2):

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).